# How to create MySQL database or tables in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, database-design

I am trying to create MySQL tables and edit existing tables in Visual Studio 2019 Community. I have tried performing these actions using the Server Explorer Window. I have also attempted to use dbForge Fusion extension. The results have been the same in both installation configurations.

Confirmed: The connection string works and I can see the list of tables in the Server Explorer. The data updates in Visual Studio if the database or tables are created or edited outside of Visual Studio.

Using a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2019 Community (reinstalled several times from scratch), and from the Server Explorer Window:

- I can view and then edit any table schema with a double click on the table in the Server Explorer. *Table schema appears as a tabbed document in the central Document Well)*.
- I can load and edit the rows of data held by the table.

From the Server Explorer Window:

- I cannot view any table schema with right-click -> Design.
- I cannot add a database or a table at all.

  - For both of the above two actions:

    - The table schema tab appears at the top of the central Document Well, but the Document Well is completely blank.
    - When I attempt to close the tab of the new table at the top of the Document Well, I am prompted for a name to save the table. Once a name is provided and I click ENTER, an error appears:

> Unable to save object with error. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1.

Dismissing the error shows that no table is created.

There is no user-entered code or SQL syntax involved in the process. I am constructing the table using only the mouse from the Server Explorer, and then closing the (failed) table by clicking on the "x".

Using

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2019 Community edition.
- MySQL 8.0.23 db served from a shared hosting server
- MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.9
- Connector/NET 6.9.8